# MySQL c++ connector is crashing in debug mode

Tags: c++, mysql

I started learning mysql c++ connector. 
I was trying with sample code given over the internet . 
But it is randomly crashing. 
It works fine in release mode. But when I use debug mode it is crashing. 
**Does I need to give (add ) any specific linking option for debug mode ?**

```
/* Standard C++ headers */
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

/* MySQL Connector/C++ specific headers */
#include <driver.h>
#include <connection.h>
#include <statement.h>
#include <prepared_statement.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <metadata.h>
#include <resultset_metadata.h>
#include <exception.h>
#include <warning.h>


#define DBHOST "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306"
#define USER "vivek"
#define PASSWORD "vivek"
#define DATABASE "user2"

#define NUMOFFSET 100
#define COLNAME 200

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;


static void retrieve_data_and_print (ResultSet *rs, int type, int colidx, string colname) {

    /* retrieve the row count in the result set */
    cout << "\nRetrieved " << rs -> rowsCount() << " row(s)." << endl;

    cout << "\nCityName" << endl;
    cout << "--------" << endl;

    /* fetch the data : retrieve all the rows in the result set */
    while (rs->next()) {
        if (type == NUMOFFSET) {
                       cout << rs -> getString(colidx) << endl;
        } else if (type == COLNAME) {
                       cout << rs -> getString(colname) << endl;
        } // if-else
    } // while

    cout << endl;

} // retrieve_data_and_print()

static void retrieve_dbmetadata_and_print (Connection *dbcon) {

    if (dbcon -> isClosed()) {
        throw runtime_error("DatabaseMetaData FAILURE - database connection closed");
    }

    cout << "\nDatabase Metadata" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;

    cout << boolalpha;

    /* The following commented statement won't work with Connector/C++ 1.0.5 and later */
    //auto_ptr < DatabaseMetaData > dbcon_meta (dbcon -> getMetaData());

    DatabaseMetaData *dbcon_meta = dbcon -> getMetaData();

    cout << "Database Product Name: " << dbcon_meta -> getDatabaseProductName() << endl;
    cout << "Database Product Version: " << dbcon_meta -> getDatabaseProductVersion() << endl;
    cout << "Database User Name: " << dbcon_meta -> getUserName() << endl << endl;

    cout << "Driver name: " << dbcon_meta -> getDriverName() << endl;
    cout << "Driver version: " << dbcon_meta -> getDriverVersion() << endl << endl;

    cout << "Database in Read-Only Mode?: " << dbcon_meta -> isReadOnly() << endl;
    cout << "Supports Transactions?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsTransactions() << endl;
    cout << "Supports DML Transactions only?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsDataManipulationTransactionsOnly() << endl;
    cout << "Supports Batch Updates?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsBatchUpdates() << endl;
    cout << "Supports Outer Joins?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsOuterJoins() << endl;
    cout << "Supports Multiple Transactions?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsMultipleTransactions() << endl;
    cout << "Supports Named Parameters?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsNamedParameters() << endl;
    cout << "Supports Statement Pooling?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsStatementPooling() << endl;
    cout << "Supports Stored Procedures?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsStoredProcedures() << endl;
    cout << "Supports Union?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsUnion() << endl << endl;

    cout << "Maximum Connections: " << dbcon_meta -> getMaxConnections() << endl;
    cout << "Maximum Columns per Table: " << dbcon_meta -> getMaxColumnsInTable() << endl;
    cout << "Maximum Columns per Index: " << dbcon_meta -> getMaxColumnsInIndex() << endl;
    cout << "Maximum Row Size per Table: " << dbcon_meta -> getMaxRowSize() << " bytes" << endl;

    cout << "\nDatabase schemas: " << endl;

    auto_ptr < ResultSet > rs ( dbcon_meta -> getSchemas());

    cout << "\nTotal number of schemas = " << rs -> rowsCount() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    int row = 1;

    while (rs -> next()) {
        cout << "\t" << row << ". " << rs -> getString("TABLE_SCHEM") << endl;
        ++row;
    } // while

    cout << endl << endl;

} // retrieve_dbmetadata_and_print()

static void retrieve_rsmetadata_and_print (ResultSet *rs) {

    if (rs -> rowsCount() == 0) {
        throw runtime_error("ResultSetMetaData FAILURE - no records in the result set");
    }

    cout << "ResultSet Metadata" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    /* The following commented statement won't work with Connector/C++ 1.0.5 and later */
    //auto_ptr < ResultSetMetaData > res_meta ( rs -> getMetaData() );

    ResultSetMetaData *res_meta = rs -> getMetaData();

    int numcols = res_meta -> getColumnCount();
    cout << "\nNumber of columns in the result set = " << numcols << endl << endl;

    cout.width(20);
    cout << "Column Name/Label";
    cout.width(20);
    cout << "Column Type";
    cout.width(20);
    cout << "Column Size" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < numcols; ++i) {
        cout.width(20);
        cout << res_meta -> getColumnLabel (i+1);
        cout.width(20);
        cout << res_meta -> getColumnTypeName (i+1);
        cout.width(20);
        cout << res_meta -> getColumnDisplaySize (i+1) << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nColumn \"" << res_meta -> getColumnLabel(1);
    cout << "\" belongs to the Table: \"" << res_meta -> getTableName(1);
    cout << "\" which belongs to the Schema: \"" << res_meta -> getSchemaName(1) << "\"" << endl << endl;

} // retrieve_rsmetadata_and_print()


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    Driver *driver;
    Connection *con;
    Statement *stmt;
    ResultSet *res;
    PreparedStatement *prep_stmt;
    Savepoint *savept;

    int updatecount = 0;

    /* initiate url, user, password and database variables */
    string url(argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : DBHOST);
    const string user(argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : USER);
    const string password(argc >= 4 ? argv[3] : PASSWORD);
    const string database(argc >= 5 ? argv[4] : DATABASE);

    try {
        driver = get_driver_instance();

        /* create a database connection using the Driver */
        con = driver -> connect(url, user, password);

        /* alternate syntax using auto_ptr to create the db connection */
        //auto_ptr  con (driver -> connect(url, user, password));

        /* turn off the autocommit */
        con -> setAutoCommit(0);

        cout << "\nDatabase connection\'s autocommit mode = " << con -> getAutoCommit() << endl;

        /* select appropriate database schema */
        con -> setSchema(database);

        /* retrieve and display the database metadata */
        retrieve_dbmetadata_and_print (con);

        /* create a statement object */
        stmt = con -> createStatement();

        cout << "Executing the Query: \"SELECT * FROM City\" .." << endl;

        /* run a query which returns exactly one result set */
        res = stmt -> executeQuery ("show datbases");

        cout << "Retrieving the result set .." << endl;

        /* retrieve the data from the result set and display on stdout */
        //retrieve_data_and_print (res, NUMOFFSET, 1, string("CityName"));


        con -> commit();


        /* Clean up */
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete prep_stmt;
        con -> close();
        delete con;

    } catch (SQLException &e) {
        cout << "ERROR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << " (" << __func__<< ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "ERROR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl;

        if (e.getErrorCode() == 1047) {
            /*
            Error: 1047 SQLSTATE: 08S01 (ER_UNKNOWN_COM_ERROR)
            Message: Unknown command
            */
            cout << "\nYour server does not seem to support Prepared Statements at all. ";
            cout << "Perhaps MYSQL < 4.1?" << endl;
        }

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {

        cout << "ERROR: runtime_error in " << __FILE__;
        cout << " (" << __func__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "ERROR: " << e.what() << endl;

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // main()
```

Comment: "It is crashing ..." - what exactly happens? Have you tried running under a debugger, or something like valgrind?

Comment: it was generating memory head stack. I fixed it by replace lib with debug mode generated lib .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a very likely error. The library is creating things for you and you are deleting them.
This could be using a different heap manager and therefore causes problems.

The API is very poor if it does that. It should provide deleters for you. Does it?

I found something like this on [their site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html#c11783) and told them what I thought:

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the connector uses different version of C++ runtime library than your application. Object created by the connector is initialized differently than the one by your application's library. Then when you destroy the object, you'd be destroying it incorrectly. You'd want to download the source code for the connector and compile it yourself.

To download the source code, go to http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/#downloads and select "source code" for the platform type.

Answer (score 0):

When in debug mode select the debug folder for you libraries instead of opt.